# How to determine which key is pressed in Leave or LostFocus event

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to check *is enter key pressed* in Leave Or LostFocus event.

When focus to DateTimePicker; I click button (Printer Button). Then Validation event of DateTimePicker trigger. I want to disable DateTimePicker when I click Button.

I need Validation of DateTimePick only when I pressed Enter Or Tab Key on DateTimePicker.

Comment: VB.NET, or VBA?  It can't be both.

Comment: I edited question. Its vb.net

Comment: Set the print button's [CausesValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#definition) property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have validation within the Preview Key Down function within the DateTimePicker Events.

```
 Private Sub DateTimePicker1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter or Tab Key Pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mark, PreviewKeyDown event didn't trigger when the mouse click. I need when pointer (cursor) is on DateTimePicker I want to click another button (actually Print Button). When I click button Validation of DateTimePicker Trigger authomatically. I want to stop that Validation when I click button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add KeyDown event handler for your DateTimePicker controller

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    'validation logic should go here
End If 
End Sub
```

Also, you need to disable the DateTimePicker control in the Leave or LostFocus event handler, if the key pressed was not ENter or Tab.This is mainly to ensures that the DateTimePicker validation is only triggered when Enter or Tab keys are pressed. You can do something like this,

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.Leave
If Not (Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Enter OrElse Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Tab) Then
    DateTimePicker1.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```